# Trying to get property “valor” of non-object laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel to create api, i have one function that create a product, but i'm getting this message:

> "trying to get property "valor" of non-object

This is part of my function that generate this error:

```
if ($atributos['variacoes'] != null)
    {
    $atributosLog = [];
    foreach($atributos['variacoes'] as $variacao)
        {
        unset($variacao['tipo']);
        $variacao['id_produto'] = $produto->id;
        $var = Variacao::create($variacao);
        foreach($variacao['atributo'] as $atributo)
            {
            $atributoLog = Atributo::create(['variacao_id' => $var->id, 'valor_atributo_id' => $atributo['idatributo']]);
            $valor = $atributoLog->valorAtributo()->first()->valor;
            $tipo = $atributoLog->valorAtributo()->first()->itemAtributo()->first()->item;
            $atributosLog[] = ["valor" => $valor, "tipo" => $tipo];
            }

        $variations[] = ["variacao" => $variacao, "atributos" => $atributosLog];
        $atributosLog = [];
        }
    }
```

Console says that the error is in this line:

```
$valor = $atributoLog->valorAtributo()->first()->valor;
```

This is my payload request:

```
  {
  "tipo_produto": 4,
  "nome_tipo_produto": "aaa",
  "nome": "dasfasfasff",
  "valor_fornecedor": 424.24,
  "indice_lucro": null,
  "sku_prin": "dasdsadda",
  "estoque": 14,
  "foto_prin_1": "https://w1.ezcdn.com.br/maze/fotos/zoom/5887fz1/tenis-nike-air-presto-essential-preto.jpg",
  "variacoes": [
    {
      "nomeatributo": "36",
      "atributo": [
        {
          "iditemAtributo": 3,
          "idatributo": 1,
          "tipovariacao": "Cor",
          "valorvariacao": "Vermelha"
        },
        {
          "iditemAtributo": 6,
          "idatributo": 2,
          "tipovariacao": "Tamanho",
          "valorvariacao": "36"
        }
      ],
      "sku": "dasfasf",
      "tipo": "Tamanho",
      "id": "",
      "id_produto": "",
      "estoque_variacao": "14",
      "linkfotovariacao": "",
      "created_at": "",
      "foto_prin_1": "https://img.estadao.com.br/resources/jpg/0/1/1531082746710.jpg",
      "foto_prin_2": "",
      "foto_prin_3": "",
      "foto_prin_4": "",
      "foto_prin_5": "",
      "foto_prin_6": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: when you foreach `variacoes` first result is      `nomeatributo`  which doesnt create on database

Comment: What is `valorAtributo()` method content ?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the model. Can you please show us the `Atributo` Model?